# Splitting Excel column into different tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to split data from an Excel column in to different tabs for each unique value.  For example, I'd like a tab for each unique value in the Concat field that lists only the records for that specific person.
[image]

Currently using this code, which splits the tabs out correctly, but each tab has all of the worksheet's data, not just the individualized data.

```
Sub parse_data()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    vcol = 5       
    Set ws = Sheets("qReconcilers")       
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:N1"           
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

How would I get those tabs to only display the data pertaining to that particular person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be ok for a beginning:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim defaultColumn           As Long
    defaultColumn = 5           'column E

    Dim wks                     As Worksheet
    Dim sourcelastRow           As Long
    Set wks = Worksheets(1)     'the main worksheet
    sourcelastRow = lastRow(wks.Name)

    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim checkCell       As Range

    For cnt = 2 To sourcelastRow
        Set checkCell = wks.Cells(cnt, defaultColumn)

        If WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Evaluate("'" & Trim(checkCell) & "'!A1")) Then
          Dim newSheet As Worksheet
          Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
          newSheet.Name = Trim(checkCell.Value2)
        End If

        Dim targetLastRow As Long
        targetLastRow = lastRow(checkCell.Value2) + 1
        Worksheets(checkCell.Value2).Rows(targetLastRow).Value2 = wks.Rows(cnt).Value2
    Next cnt

End Sub

Public Function lastRow(Optional strSheet As String, _
                        Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet As Worksheet
    If strSheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(strSheet)
    End If
    lastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

What the code does:

- loops through every cell in column number 5 of the first worksheet;
- checks whether there is a worksheet with the name of this column";
  `WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Evaluate("'" & Trim(checkCell) & "'!A1"))`
- if there is no such worksheet - it creates it;
- then finds the worksheet with this column and at the row after the last used row of the worksheet it writes the values of the corresponding row;

Comment: Is there a way to include the headers in those tabs?

Comment: The header is the first row. Simply write         `Worksheets(checkCell.Value2).Rows(1).Value2 = wks.Rows(1).Value2` on the line before `Dim targetLastRow As Long` in the code above, @Katie